# Microservices API Gateway Design Pattern - Creating Endpoints

Tags: architecture, microservices, api-gateway

Given that I want to use the API Gateway pattern, and I have a series of microservices in which requests should be forwarded onto, how should I make the Gateway aware of what endpoints to create for each microservice, and what level of authorisation / permisisons are required by users to access those endpoints?

Comment: IMHO this question is too general to be able to provide valuable feedback on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you've implemented your gateway, but in general you would need to manually create the endpoints that you want to expose on your gateway, and configure how these map to your underlying services. This applies to auth too, there's no way for your gateway to know who should be able to access each endpoint without you configuring it for the endpoint (or a group of endpoints) manually.

You may not want to expose all your microservice endpoints on the gateway depending on the strategy you decide upon. For example, you may well want to allow internal communication between microservices to happen directly (bypassing the gateway), and only expose endpoints that are used by a UI/3rd party on the gateway.

Comment: Would it be unwise for the gateway to be blocked initially, have each microservice send information about the endpoints that it wants as well as auth requirements, construct those endpoints and then allow requests?

Comment: Honestly that sounds excessive, unless you're planning to have hundreds of microservices that have their endpoints changing very frequently, I'd just do it manually. You could define your endpoints using the OpenAPI Specification if you're not already, then load these in to your gateway - either directly if it's an off-the-shelf gateway, or with a code generation tool if you're building your own.